# Different versions of the rMarkdown package compile a .Rmd differently

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

#### Edit

Thanks to some SO (i.e., @tmpname12345) users, I've come to the conclusion that my problem (described below) is likely caused by the differences between `v0.2.64` and `v0.3.11` of `rmarkdown`.  The question now becomes:

Is there a way I can prevent `rmarkdown` version `0.3.11` and `knitr` from adding a line after the title of a .pdf file?

#### Original Question

I've come across a curious difference between compiling a .pdf document with the same `yaml` header block on two different computers with Rstudio and `knitr`.  The difference is that on one computer, an additional line is inserted after the title while on the other, the line is not inserted (the preferred behavior).  I would like to prevent the line from being inserted regardless of where the document is compiled.

I am using 32-bit R 3.1.2 on both computers.  The `yaml` block is identical between both computers.

Here is the `.Rmd` file:

```
---
title: Header Test
output: pdf_document  
---
My@gmail.com\hfill \hfill Address  
Phone number\hfill \hfill Town, State, ZIP
```

Evidence of no additional line after the title, generated from my laptop **with `rmarkdown` version `0.2.64`**:
[image: File generated from my laptop]

Evidence of the additional line after the title, generated from my desktop **with `rmarkdown` version `0.3.11`**:
[image: File generated from my desktop]

Initially, I thought it may have been a function of the `knitr` package version, so I upgraded the package in the second image *from* 1.7 to the newest available version on `CRAN`, 1.9, but the extra line still remains.

I have also considered that this is an artifact of the Rstudio version on my laptop but if it is, I don't want to upgrade as the first image is the preferred.

I routinely edit .Rmd files in my Google Drive folder from both a desktop computer and my laptop, accessing the same file.  Unfortunately, they compile differently.  I prefer that there is no line added after the title.  At this point, I don't want to change anything on my laptop, fearing that compilation will start to include the extra line.

Is there some way I can force `knitr` to *not* add the additional line?

Comment: are you using the same tex distro? can you vimdiff the latex code between the two machines

Comment: Both machines are running `MikTex 2.9`.  I hate to admit this but I don't know how to vimdiff the latex code.

Comment: or just compare them by eye since they should be short. what platforms are you running.. oh you're using markdown, nevermind

Comment: My guess is different versions of rmarkdown. The header type for tex files was changed recently.

Comment: AH!  Thanks @tmpname12345.  I hadn't even considered that it could have been a change in `rmarkdown` versions.  I've updated the question to be simply "How can I prevent `rmarkdown v0.3.11` from including an extra line after the title?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create your own latex template that formats the header like you want. You can use the default template as a starting point [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/inst/rmd/latex/default.tex). Then save the file as .tex in the same directory as your Rmd file and add this to the yaml header:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    template: mytemplate.tex
```

Comment: I've written exactly one very simple LaTeX document.  For now, I ended up copying/pasting in the `default.tex` from the older `rmarkdown` package version into the new directory.  That's the short-term fix.  The longer-term fix is learning more about LaTeX.